# Using `sub` to rename columns in data frame

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to use `sub` to rename columns in a large data frame, but got stuck with using `replacement` and `x` arguments.
I have a data frame like below:

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:12))
colnames(df) <- c("A_number", "A_frq", "B_number", "B_frq")
```

I need the column names to be `colnames(df) <- c("A", "frq A", "B", "frq B")`. My actual data has many more columns so I'm trying to use patterns to rename every column at once.

I was able to change `A_number` and `B_number` into `A` and `B` using this: 
`colnames(df) <- sub("\\_number$", "", colnames(df))`. But I was trying to change `A_frq` and `B_frq` after this, and tried `colnames(df) <- sub("\\_frq$", "", paste("frq ", colnames(df)))`, which changes all column names to `frq A` or `frq B`. I also thought about using `colnames(df) <- sub("\\_frq$", "", colnames(df))` and adding `frq` later, but then all columns are now `A` or `B` and I can't pick out which were `A_frq` or `B_frq`. Is there a simple way to use `sub` to solve this?

Comment: It is not recommended to have column names with spaces.  They will likely produce unintended consequences when you go to retrieve the columns.  What's wrong with the existing names?

Comment: ?`str_replace_all()` What do you want to change `A-frq` and `B_frq` to?

Comment: @RichScriven I was trying to edit it because I have functions that read csv files with specific column names (in the format I'm changing) and changing column names seemed easier than going through the functions. I wasn't aware that having column names with spaces is not recommended though, so maybe I'll end up editing the functions.

Comment: @NelsonGon I'm trying to change it so that it's "frq A" and "frq B" (or following RichScriven's advice, "frq_A" and "frq_B")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When replacing, you can also refer back to part of the found value, where "\1" (so "\1" in R) means: the first part between parentheses.

```
colnames(df) <- sub("(.)_frq$", "frq \\1", colnames(df))
```

This will replace everything like "X_frq" with "frq X", and names that don't match are left unchanged.

But as said in the comments, maybe a name without spaces might be a better idea.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll probably end up editing functions, but it's great to learn that I can use "\1", thank you for the suggestion!